# How to fill in user data in an excel spreadsheet based on a cell with the users UPN

Tags: c#, excel, microsoft-graph-api

I have a mailing on internal users in an excel document. We have the users UPN in a cell. I want to take a call to the Graph API to fill in additional data. Here in an example table like the excel file is configured.

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UPN | Business area | location | State | Region | Market | Job title | Department |

I don't want to just load in the [odata as explained in this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/get-office-365-data-in-excel-using-ms-graph-api/) because we have over nearly 100,000 users.

Should I look at using the C# graph API SDK or is there a way using the Get Data functionality to load just the users and details I need?

Comment: we can use the PowerShell to do it, we can use import-csv in PowerShell: https://lazyadmin.nl/powershell/import-csv-powershell/

Comment: @MehtabSiddique How would you do this an achieve the requirements of not pulling all of that data?

Comment: Check the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties, I'm not sure if Graph API provides users properties like business area, market and region. Maybe under different names but it must be clear what exactly you need.  What do you mean by location? Office number?

Comment: Where is the excel file users UPN stored? On local machine, sharepoint, onedrive?

Comment: @Joseph can you answer the last two questions above? Would be good to get those answers so we know exactly what we’re working with.

Comment: @user2250152 Yes. The attributes are available under the Graph API. You can see the the properties available by that call: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

Comment: @user2250152 I can host the document any place.

Comment: @Skin answered questions. Just to be clear I know how to pull data from the graph API. I can do that from the CLI. I am wondering how we pull that data into the excel document. Do I need to do embed script? What options are there?

Comment: Yes but the reason why we ask is because if it’s on SharePoint or in OneDrive, there are a raft of cloud based approaches. Even Graph has Excel based update functionality. If you can “host it anywhere” then we’ll give you a solution off that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of connecting to Microsoft Graph REST APIs from Power Query (Get Data functionality in the Excel) isn't recommended or supported, you need to use alternative solution.

I can share a simple example how to write data into the Excel file stored on local file system.

For reading Excel file on the local file system, you can use `NPOI` NuGet. For calling Graph API from C# I would recommend `Microsoft.Graph` NuGet.

```
// class for working with xlsx file
XSSFWorkbook xssfwb;
var fileName = @"<path_to_xlsx_file>";
using (var file = File.OpenRead(fileName))
{
    // load content of the file
    xssfwb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
}

// get first sheet
var sheet = xssfwb.GetSheetAt(0);
// iterate rows
// starting on the second row, supposing that the first row contains columns headers
var rowNumber = 1;
while (true)
{
    var row = sheet.GetRow(rowNumber);
    // for empty row GetRow returns null which indicates that all rows were processed
    if (row == null)
    {
        break;
    }
    // get user principal name
    var upn = row.Cells[0].StringCellValue;
    try
    {
        // use upn for call to Graph API, use select method to specify 
        // a limited set of properties you need and to minimize 
        // the size of the response
        var user = async graphClient.Users[upn].Request().Select("property1,property2,...").GetAsync();

        // if there is only one column in the row the rest of columns
        // must be created
        if (row.Cells.Count == 1)
        {
            row.CreateCell(1); // Business area
            row.CreateCell(2); // location
            row.CreateCell(3); // State
            row.CreateCell(4); // Region
            row.CreateCell(5); // Market
            row.CreateCell(6); // Job title
            row.CreateCell(7); // Department
        }
        // set values
        row.Cells[1].SetCellValue(user.property1);
        row.Cells[2].SetCellValue(user.property2);
        row.Cells[3].SetCellValue(user.property3);
        row.Cells[4].SetCellValue(user.property4);
        row.Cells[5].SetCellValue(user.property5);
        row.Cells[6].SetCellValue(user.property6);
        row.Cells[7].SetCellValue(user.property7);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle exceptions either from Graph API or from NPOI
        // throttling, non-existing users, etc.
    }
    // iterate row
    rowNumber++;
}
// save result
using (var file = File.Create(fileName))
{
    xssfwb.Write(file);
}
```

The challenge is that you have 100,000 records in the Excel file and I'm not sure about the performance of the whole solution and it's quite possible that it won't meet your expectations.

References:

[NPOI](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi)

[Lack of Support for Microsoft Graph in Power Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connecting-to-graph)

[Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet)

Comment: I think that is what I was looking for! Thank you. We don't have 100,000 users in the spreadsheet just in the organization so this approach seems to be perfect. Do you know if you can do this from inside of the Excel online scripting tools?

Comment: @Joseph I have no experience with Excel online scripting tools